# Isuue with writing Selenium Code in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am very new with Ruby programming and I'm facing an issue while writing the following Selenium code:

```
class LaunchWebBrowser  
  def initialize  
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox  
  end  
end  
d = LaunchWebBrowser.new  
d.browser()
```

Console Output:

> F:/RUBY
>   WORKSPACE/newProject/myFirstRubyProject/LaunchWebBrowser.rb:3:in
>   `initialize': uninitialized constant LaunchWebBrowser::Selenium
>   (NameError)   from F:/RUBY
>   WORKSPACE/newProject/myFirstRubyProject/LaunchWebBrowser.rb:6:in`new'
>     from F:/RUBY
>   WORKSPACE/newProject/myFirstRubyProject/LaunchWebBrowser.rb:6:in
>   `'

Comment: have you `require 'selenium'` first?

Comment: when I am using require 'selenium' or require 'selenium-webdriver' , Eclipse is displaying 'The word 'Selenium' is not correctly spelled' on hovering mouse on the text. I am not getting this only for selenium but for all statements with 'require'.